# Which is the distribution of this data set

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

We have a test with possible scores from 0 to 100 and a sample of 20 subjects which have the score: 87,53,35,90,78,45,65,87,76,57,86,99,67,98,86,79,90,88,86,95.
mean=77.35; standard deviation=17.55.

Is this distribution normal or not? Can we use normalized classes to differentiate between subjects?

Thank you!

Comment: Hint for the first question: The support of your data is $[0,100]$, The support of the normal distribution is $(-\infty,+\infty)$.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Yes, you can. Normal distribution is used in such problems to approximate the true distribution, so the support is not a problem. Moreover normal distribution gives almost zero weight to values more than 3-4 standard deviations aways from the mean. But firstly check (by a histogram perhaps) that the values are normally distributed, i.e. they are symmetrically distributed around the mean.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to say for sure whether these test scores
are from a normal population. 
There is a variety of ways to see if data are a 'reasonable fit'
to normal.

**Three graphical methods.** Here are three common graphical methods:

> (1) Make a *Histogram* of
>   the data and judge see whether a sample seems consistent
>   with the well-known normal 'bell curve' shape. One can plot
>   the density curve of the 'best-fitting' normal density (in which
>   we set $\mu = \bar X$ and $\sigma = S$).
>
> (2) Because some information is lost when observations
>   are sorted into 'bins' for a histogram, a more accurate
>   method is to compare a plot of the empirical cumulative
>   distribution function *ECDF* of a sample (in which, roughly
>   speaking, each of $n$
>   observations is assigned probability $1/n$) with the
>   best-fitting normal CDF. Then try to judge whether the points
>   of the ECDF are a good fit to the CDF.
>
> (3) The vertical scale of the ECDF plot can be transformed
>   so that the normal CDF becomes a straight line. In such
>   a plot one need only judge whether the data fit a straight
>   line 'reasonably well'. The result
>   in called a *normal probability plot* or a *quantile-quantile*
>   plot of the data.

Each kind of plot is shown below. Perhaps owing mainly to the
relatively large proportion of scores in the 80s, none of the three shows a good fit of your exam data to normal.

[image]

**Numerical tests of normality.** Furthermore, there are many formal numerical tests of normality.
The null hypothesis is that the data are consistent with a random sample from a
normal population and the alternative hypothesis is that they are
not. The test statistics attempt to quantify the 'goodness of fit'
of the ECDF to the CDF or of the normal probability plot to a
straight line.

One formal test that is generally recognized as having good
properties is the Shapiro-Wilk test. A printout of the
result of this test for your test data, as implemented in R statistical software, is shown below. The low P-value indicates
that the data do not appear to be consistent with a random
sample from a normal population. (The Anderson-Darling test
of normality from Minitab also has a P-value around 2%.)

```
 > shapiro.test(x)

         Shapiro-Wilk normality test

 data:  x 
 W = 0.8894, p-value = 0.02626
```

Makers of standardized tests (SAT, ACT, GRE and so on) expend
considerable effort to ask questions that yield normally distributed
scores across the population of people who take such tests. It is
not surprising if results from one class exam in a university or
high school class result in scores that are not consistent with
normal.